# Serving Fonts on Cloudfront with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, font-face

I’m trying to setup with Cloudfront on Heroku following the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-with-rails

Cloudfront is serving css and js assets fine, but I can’t get the font icons to be served.
I have my icon font in assets/fonts and I'm loading the fonts in the stylesheet like this:

```
@font-face {
  src: font-url('dripicons.eot');
  ...
}
```

The Cloudfront url is not getting prefixing with full Cloudfront URL (it's missing the subdomain). It looks like this:

```
https://.cloudfront.net/assets/dripicons-9b4649c1936652d1c1c1d18410b16ebd.eot
```

I tried using the font_assets gem (https://github.com/rubymaverick/font_assets), but it didn't fix the issue. I'm using Rails 3.2.13.

I'd really appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: did u set `config.font_assets.origin` in your `config/environments/production.rb` file ?

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL is missing for your font it could be a configuration issue. Please, verify that your environment configuration files (in this case the `production.rb` one) is correctly configured. From the [font_assets guide](https://github.com/rubymaverick/font_assets#usage):

```
config.font_assets.origin = 'http://coffeescript.codeschool.com'
```

You should probably an adequate origin URL here.