# Heroku / Cloudfront / Fonts / Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku, fonts, amazon-cloudfront

There are quite a few SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413639/heroku-cdn-cloudfront-fonts-firefox-bugs), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006305/firefox-does-not-render-fonts-from-cloudfront), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061213/serving-fonts-on-cloudfront-with-heroku), etc.)  that go over the same problem I am having (fonts are not displaying on FireFox due to CORS issue). I have tried all of the proposed solutions in the above questions as well as various blog posts that come up when Googling the issue.

In my specific case I am using Cloudfront on Heroku but I am not using S3 (my assets are pulled to the CDN on first request). I am also using site-wide SSL (and I'm not sure if this is what is causing my issues as all the other examples seem to be for http:// sites). Currently I am trying to use the [font_assets gem](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets) but when I curl one of my font files (or even a jpg file) I am getting a 301 Moved Permanently instead of a 200.

```
 curl -i https://d2loy3ox2q4ikr.cloudfront.net/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9a3b8f90662fe9149f07a059f1a4c782.woff
 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Content-Type: text/html
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 12:27:33 GMT
 Location: https://www.transdraft.com/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9a3b8f90662fe9149f07a059f1a4c782.woff
 Status: 301 Moved Permanently
 X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
 Via: 1.1 1316c66c042cd4b103a533bbf48877a5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
 X-Amz-Cf-Id: NciaYbAYVS7OpY6ORzjeZMurd_cyBo-B1WfN1QZbSexbM2DoD0vWqg==

 curl -i https://d2loy3ox2q4ikr.cloudfront.net/assets/transdraft-hp-2-0fa26dc608ff6a3ea83a093dce8e6338.jpg
 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
 Content-Type: text/html
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 12:28:47 GMT
 Location: https://www.transdraft.com/assets/transdraft-hp-2-0fa26dc608ff6a3ea83a093dce8e6338.jpg
 Status: 301 Moved Permanently
 X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
 Via: 1.1 c8b893f88c46deef2c0f22aefa2d3ecc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
 X-Amz-Cf-Id: 897u3X7te5f167cZlJiBME1UlBp5NYtGrKm18D4FWOHlTEFMITYTLw==
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this same issue by modifying my `application.css.scss` to use SCSS imports instead of requires.

From:

```
//= require font-awesome
```

To:

```
@import 'font-awesome';
```

This may not work for you if you're not using SCSS.